# Unable to access props passed to a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using React and Redux, But when I am passing data from container to the child components. The props is becoming an empty object.
This is my Container component.

```
class HeaderContainer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <Header searchByName = {this.props.searchByName} />
    }

}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        searchByName: searchProviderByName.searchProviderByName
    }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(HeaderContainer);
```

But when I am trying to access the data in the child component. It is coming as empty object.

```
export default function Header(props) {
 const performSearch = () => {
        props.searchByName(name,location); // getting undefined, props is empty object
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you add any *codesandbox* example? Here it is looking fine. But an example will help to fix the bug. It will be good if you start using `useDispatch` hook from `react-redux` instead of HOC with `mapDispatchToProps`.

Comment: @SandipNirmal Why would it be better to use `useDispatch`?

Comment: Is the `Header` functional component *the same* `Header` component returned in `HeaderContainer`? I.E. when you access `props.searchByName` is it a `Header` component rendered by `HeaderContainer` or some *other* export? Why not just connect `Header` to your redux store instead? Side note: the `connect` HOC mapDispatchToProps will automagically wrap actions with a call to dispatch, so no need for all that extra boilerplate.

Comment: @Swapnil Firstly it makes your code lot cleaner, and it can reduce re-render caused by HOC in few cases. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-hooks-replace-render-props-and-higher-order-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken the code from your question and can show that it works just fine (see snippet below). Either you messed up an import or `searchProviderByName.searchProviderByName` is undefined but then Header would still not receive an empty props.

It is not possible to indicate what's wrong with your code because code provided in question works, maybe you can provide a snippet or sandbox that demonstrates the problem you have.

```js
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
const {
  createStore,
  applyMiddleware,
  compose,
  bindActionCreators,
} = Redux;

const initialState = {};
//action types
const SOME_ACTION = 'SOME_ACTION';
//action creators
const someAction = (...args) => ({
  type: SOME_ACTION,
  payload: args,
});
const reducer = (x) => x;
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) => {
      console.log('action:', action);
      return next(action);
    })
  )
);

function Header(props) {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => props.searchByName()}>
      click me
    </button>
  );
}
class HeaderContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Header searchByName={this.props.searchByName} />
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      searchByName: someAction,
    },
    dispatch
  );
};

const App = connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(HeaderContainer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```